# matDatepickerFilter custom function selectable dates cannot be selected (Angular Material v15)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a custom function to filter dates which successfully disables dates which I don't want to be selected, however the dates which are clickable do nothing when I click on them, no errors or anything. If I remove the filter or use the example filter from material docs it works, but I don't know how or why my filter disables all the dates to be selected, when the calendar looks fine.

My calendar

[image]

Html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="m-2" subscriptSizing="dynamic">
        <input
          [(ngModel)]="bookingService.selectedRooms[key.key].arrival_date"
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="arrival_date"
          name="inputoosStartDate"
          (dateChange)="tableService.setArrivalDate(key.key, $event)"
          [matDatepickerFilter]="createDateFilter(key.key)"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
          matIconSuffix
          [for]="arrival_date"
        ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #arrival_date></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Ts

```
 public createDateFilter(roomId: string): any {
    return this.tableService.getBookedDayFilter(Number(roomId));
 }
```

tableService

```
public getBookedDayFilter(roomId: number): any {
    return (date: Date | null): boolean => {
      if (!date) {
        return false;
      }
      const modifiedDate = new Date(date);
      return this.dateService.isDateBooked(
        new Date(modifiedDate.setDate(modifiedDate.getDate() + 1)),
        Number(roomId)
      );
    };
  }
```

dateService

```
public isDateBooked(date: Date, roomId: number): boolean {
    for (const booking of this.bookingService.bookings) {
      if (
        booking.room_id === roomId &&
        booking.booking_id !== this.calendarService.selectedBooking?.booking_id
      ) {
        const arrivalDate = new Date(booking.arrival_date).getTime();
        const departureDate = new Date(booking.departure_date).getTime();
        const questionedDate = date.getTime();

        if (arrivalDate <= questionedDate && questionedDate <= departureDate) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative solution.

Put a click event on the mat form field where I assign the roomId to a variable and then use the arrow function like this:

```
dateFilter = (date: Date): boolean => {
    if (!date) {
      return false;
    }
    const modifiedDate = new Date(date);
    console.log('working fos ', this.fosNumber);

    return this.dateService.isDateBooked(
      new Date(modifiedDate.setDate(modifiedDate.getDate())),
      Number(this.roomId)
    );
  };
```